How Can Dead Click Data Guide UI Design Enhancements?
Dead clicks are an indicator of user frustration in a user interface. How can dead click metrics, such as those provided by tools like Microsoft Clarity, be used to identify areas of friction in a UI and inform design decisions? Specifically, what strategies can be applied to interpret this data and prioritize improvements to enhance the user experience?
